# How to get ngModel value on Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, angular-ngmodel, mobile-development

I'm trying to pass the values of inputs from html to ts file with ngModel. But I get an error. Here is my code, error, and versions.

```
signup.html
<ion-content padding>
<ion-label color="black" stacked>Ad - Soyad</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" id="name_surname"  [(ngModel)]="name" name='name'></ion-input>
<ion-label color="black" stacked>Kullanıcı Adı</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" id="username" [(ngModel)]="username" name='username'></ion-input>
<ion-label color="black" stacked>Kullanıcı Mail Adresi</ion-label>
<ion-input type="email" id="email" [(ngModel)]="email" name='email'></ion-input>
<ion-label color="black" stacked>Kullanıcı Şifresi</ion-label>
<ion-input type="password" id="password" [(ngModel)]="password" name='password'></ion-input>
<ion-label color="black" stacked>Kullanıcı Şifresi - Tekrardan</ion-label>
<ion-input type="password" id="password_control" [(ngModel)]="password_control" name='password_control'></ion-input>
<ion-label color="black" stacked>Kullanıcı Tipi</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" id="type" [(ngModel)]="type" name='type'></ion-input>
<button ion-button full (click)='signupHTTP()' id="signupButton">Giriş Yap</button>
</ion-content>
```

And here is my ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


import { RequestServiceProvider } from '../../providers/request-service/request-service';



@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-signup',
  templateUrl: 'signup.html',
})
export class SignupPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public httpClient: HttpClient, private requestService : RequestServiceProvider) {
  }

  signupHTTP(){
     console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVPEp.png)

[My versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRwKK.png)

Comment: Where have you declared your `ngModel` variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define those variables as properties of your class, they can't just appear from nowhere.

```
export class SignupPage {
  name: string = 'initialName';
  username: string = 'initialUserName';
  ...
```